# Sum columns in dataframe where column name is like a string, and output to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column that is the sum of values from some other columns if the column name is like some string.

Example:

df

|  | A | B | C_1 | C_2 | C_3 | C_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 5 |

I'd like to add a new column to this dataframe that is the sum of values from any column that starts with 'C_'.  There could be one 'C_' or many of them.

New df output would look like:

|  | A | B | C_1 | C_2 | C_3 | C_x | C_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 13 |

I'm currently doing this by counting the 'C_' columns and then running a for loop across the dataframe line by line, it's not pretty or efficient, but was looking for something better.

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with parameter `like` I believe:

```
df["C_sum"] = df.filter(like="C").sum(axis=1)
```

which filters the frame such that only those that has `C` in their name remains. Then we sum the rows of that subset and put it back as `C_sum` column,

to get

```
   A  B  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_x  C_sum
0  1  1    1    2    2    4      9
1  2  2    3    3    2    5     13
```

---

If you want to be more explicit, e.g, "starts with `C_`", you can go for the `regex` parameter:

```
df["C_sum"] = df.filter(regex="^C_").sum(axis=1)
```